# What scala-library dependenecy version can be used with Gradle 7.2 for Gatling performance testing

Tags: scala, gradle, gatling

I am trying to do performance testing for my API using Gatling and Scala.
Below are the plugins/libraries I am using

> gradle version  : 7.2

> gradle.plugin.com.github.lkishalmi.gatling:gradle-gatling-plugin:3.3.0

> dependency :  gatling 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.10'

I get the below error when I try to resolve dependencies

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':performance-test'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.10] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

My guess is that the scala version 2.13.10 is not compatible with the gradle version 7.2. I tried changing the scala version to latest and many others, but nothing seems to work.

I have also seen another project using gradle 6.6 and scala version 2.12.2 which works. In my case I can't downgrade the gradle version, unfortunately.

Does anyone know what scala version is compatible with gradle 7.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The com.github.lkishalmi.gatling:gradle-gatling-plugin plugin has been deprecated for a long time. Please use the official plugin: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/extensions/gradle_plugin/

Comment: Thanks for  that.. I tried it and got below exception                                                                * Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'io.gatling.gradle', version: '3.8'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.gatling.gradle:io.gatling.gradle.gradle.plugin:3.8')

Comment: 3.8 is not a valid version. The latest version atm is 3.8.4, see https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.gatling.gradle